# How to know if function in c++ are unused if they are in a class?

Tags: c++

Is there a method to know if a private function isn't used within the definition class?
Also, I need to know if there some public function of the class which is not used outside the class. How can achieve this?

Comment: You can't know that.  Those members can be used in other headers/libraries/binaries.  You'd need static analysis tool for that.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the function and see if you get a compiler error?

Comment: For ODR-used, there are tools which give useful results. For used as in "ever executed", you need to solve the halting-problem first, unless you accept maybe.

Comment: @nwp Removing a function from a class body could make the whole project to recompile for a long time. Not a great option ...

Comment: @nwp I have a lot of function in my class, I don't want to spent a lot of time commenting and uncommenting functions to check if they are used or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends heavily on the situation.

In many cases, you can simply `grep` or `ag` the source for calls to the function.  Also, there are tools like `cppcheck` that can analyze a source base and tell you this.

However, if you don't have source then there are other methods.

Add code to the functions that will output somehow visibly (perhaps to a logfile) when called.  This is what gcc's [Code Coverage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov)  functions do.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have the code, I will take a look to cppcheck.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the function and see whether your project still compiles and links.

You should remove the definition (in the cpp file) only, and leave the declaration in the header. Otherwise overload resolution could mask the places where your function is called.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Anyway, I have a lot of function in my class and I'd like an automatic way to achieve my aim